# Best approach for continually scanning bluetooth devices on iOS as well as storing the peripheral data in background?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, bgprocessingtask

I am currently using **CoreBluetooth** to scan for peripherals. Every 30 seconds it sends its packet of information to the cloud by using a Timer. This is working good in foreground. I would like this exact operation to function seamlessly in the background too.

I have declared a CBUUID ahead of time for it seek out the designated peripheral in the background. Upon entering background mode, the scan stops functioning after 10~ seconds. How do I continually make the scan operate continue in the background?

I was looking into Bluetooth [State Preservation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518819-centralmanager), would this alleviate the issue? Should it also not be on the main thread?

After the packets are advertised I would like them stored in memory. I am aware the DiscoverPeripherals logs the peripherals... is it possible to log the RSSI and additional peripheral data in chronological order and have it an operation take affect per an interval? I was looking at BGProcessingTask to fire off a function in the background. Would a better approach be to use CoreData to store the memory and clear it after? Best/easy suggestion is appreicated.

I have changed the CBUUID to the right peripheral for `centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [uuid], options: nil)`
with uuid being the CBUUID. That seem to be allowing the peripheral to be detected in the background. It stopped logging the scan after a short period of time. Right when I put the app in background, it functions properly for a bit. I theorize it could just be calling it on the same thread and it may not be operating in the background all together. I did test this by changing the the withServices to nil, the result was that the operating was not being logged at all once I closed to the background.

I was expecting the operation to continually be scanning on the basis of the Timer every period, after the period is up it would send it the cloud just how it was doing it in the foreground.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of restrictions on iOS apps when they are not in the foreground.  Once an app moves from the foreground it is suspended and can only execute in the background for specific reasons and for limited durations.

In general, anything based on a `Timer` will not fire when the app is not in the foreground.

Some Core Bluetooth events are delivered while your app is in the background:

- Pending `connect` operations can complete with a corresponding delivery to your app.
- Peripheral disconnections will be delivered to your app
- GATT Notify/Indicate operations from a connected peripheral will be delivered to your app.
- Discovery of *new* peripherals advertising a service that you are specifically scanning for will be delivered to your app.

It is this last behaviour that you are relying on.

While you have done the right thing by specifying the specific service you are interested in, your plans are being thwarted by the fact that Core Bluetooth will not deliver *repeated* discovery notifications for a particular peripheral.

When your app is in the foreground you can use the [`CBCentralManagerAllowDuplicatesKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerscanoptionallowduplicateskey) option to request a discovery notification each time a peripheral advertisement is seen, even if an advertisement from that peripheral has been seen before.  This option has no effect when your app is not in the background.

The best way to gather data on a periodic basis from a peripheral (whether in the background or foreground) is for that peripheral to send its data via Notify/Indicate, however you seem to be trying to scan for the existence of peripherals rather than gather specific data from them, so this may not work for you.

When one of the supported Core Bluetooth background events occurs and your app has been jettisoned, State restoration allows your app to respond after iOS relaunches your app.  It will not help you in this case.

It probably isn't possible to do what you want, at least not without changing the behaviour of your peripheral.

Comment: I have adjusted the behavior of the peripheral name so the scanner does look for a specific name(s) for peripherals. You mention how Core Bluetooth will not deliver repeated discover notifications for a particular peripheral. I am looking for numerous peripherals that share a same CBUUID

Comment: Would using a Background Tasks framework override the repeated discovery notifications for a continuous period? Specifically the BGProcessing allow for a timer trigger to occur in background for periodic scans?

Comment: I did try using the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier with the method UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask along with the timer being called and it did seem to iterate for a set period in the background and invoke the BLE service of Scanning. It does not seem like a 'safe' approach though, as it did not invoke the body of the didDiscoverScan func in background

Comment: You are correct that it is not "safe".  Your app can execute indefinitely in the background while running under Xcode.   If you are not running under Xcode then your app will be terminated after about 3 minutes if you don't end your background task

Comment: I have adjusted my code, so on scan of certain items it will automatically connect. The Notify/Indicate approach works in background for connect/disconnect for logger. Is it possible to have a cloud function (send data to cloud) execute in the background on initial connect?

Comment: So if there is a disconnect, and then a reconnect-- it would grab the payload of data from background and send it to the cloud?

Comment: If not possible-- can we store BLE data in background memory a certain amount of times for each initial connection? I am looking at UserDefaults.

Comment: Then after X amount of payloads execute the function in background (is possible) or persist the data to foreground and on success just reset the memory?

Comment: Each time your app "wakes up" in the background in response to a Bluetooth background event (connect/disconnect/notify) you have a few seconds to execute other code; This is typically plenty of time to send some data over the network.  I wouldn't store this sort of data in user defaults.  Core Data would be more appropriate.  Then you can store records when the network isn't available or you can store records and send them in a batch when you have stored a number of them or whatever you want.